# Could not open the requested socket: Address already in use: bind- Android Studio

Tags: android

[I am adding Google Endpoint but this error ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aREiF.png)

Comment: check for port if you are already running a server ?if yes kill that process .

Comment: no process is running on that port